# .Net Core decorator pattern: Calling method from same service

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, decorator

I am trying to apply the decorator pattern to wrap all needed methods from a service in an exception handler, to increase testability and to keep the code clean.

The callchain is like this:

- EntityService.UpdateEntities (gets List of entities, passes to next method using foreach)
- EntityService.UpdateSingleEntity (executes the actual update)

UpdateEntities:

```
            var entities = await _context.Entities.Where(criteria).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
            entities.ForEach(async e => await UpdateEntity(e));
```

Here, UpdateEntity from the same service is called, without first calling the decorator

These methods need to be split because I will need the last method in another part of the software

Problem is, because I am calling the method from the same service, the decorator is skipped.
Of course, if I would inject the service into itself using constructor injection, a stack overflow exception would occur.

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: If you need to reuse the logic in your decorator, you could have a shared static/extension method that both your service and the decorator call, or have the shared code injected into both decorator and the service.

Comment: I would really like to keep all exception handling code out of the service and in the decorator. So my goal really is to make sure the decorator method of UpdateEntity is called, instead of UpdateEntity itself.

Comment: A decorator can't modify the class's behavior from inside the class. If you are calling from inside the service decorated, there is no way you could override the method to call decorator's method if your logic is all in the decorator, unless you explicitly decorate `this` service, in which makes the decorator useless. If you have full control of the service code, you might want to think out of the box and consider exception handling is a dependent service to the service, so you could inject exception handling code into your service, rather than decorate it. My 2 cents.